# Grails Domain Classes Primary Key

Tags: grails, primary-key, grails-domain-class

class Ctr_country {

```
    String ctr_name
    String ctr_abrev

    String toString(){
        ctr_abrev
    }
}
```

I am using SQLS Express as database. I want the primary key of this class (table) to be ctr_abrev.

a) How can i do so ?

Comment: Just a helpful FYI, underscores in class names and attributes are frowned upon in the Java/Groovy world.  CtrCountry, ctrName, ctrAbrev would be better.  Grails will underscore the table/column names in your db schema or you can control them in the mapping, similar to the answer given on the ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static mapping = {
  id generator:'assigned', name:'ctr_abrev'
}
```

[Grails Docs GORM id](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html)

Comment: hm thanks for the fast answer. Any problem the view of scafauldinf displaying this: "Ctr_country not found with id null" after adding 1 country ?

Comment: Grails scaffolding expects there to be a property called id on the class. You have two options: change scaffolding to use ctr_abrev instead of id, or change the class so that the id property maps to the ctr_abrev column. `String id
    String ctr_name

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned', column: 'ctr_abrev'`